# Fixed column header scrolling not working when viewed in Browser(IE)

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am trying to freeze all column headers in a report when scrolling, and it is working properly in BIDS. But when I run this in report manager (IE browser) it is not working. I have done this feature by going to `Advance mode-->Row Groups-->Static-->Properties` and set `FixedData` to `True`, `KeepWithGroup` to `After`, `RepeatOnNewPage` to `True`.

Could anyone let me know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a table or a matrix?

Comment: No. i am using table

Comment: did this ever worked for you ?

Answer (score -1):

You should try doing this by right clicking on your table and going to Tablix Properties. The below screen will pop up. Click on Repeat Header Rows on each Page and Keep Header Rows Visible While Scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this process but not working in IE.

Comment: I'm running IE 10 and it works consistently for me. It could be a version issue (try searching for the issue including your IE version #) or some part of your report could be interfering (try testing with a new, simplified report to see if it works at all).

Comment: Could you please let me know whether header columns can be freezed when the report is exported to Excel.

Comment: I do not know. Try searching for the answer or testing.

Comment: Please verify your answer before posting @TPhe as your answer is not correct.